# Handling "noisy" edit summaries in the "Suggested Edits" review queue

Tags: discussion

A user has recently been suggesting many edits (such as [this one](https://biology.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/63296) — screenshot below) with attempts to include links in the 
"Edit Summary".

[image]

Many of these edits seem reasonable, but having links in the summary seem inappropriate and unhelpful to me. Is there a consensus on this and if so what would be the best way to communicate that to the user?

Comment: Spelling corrections and so on are usually ok. If the edit changes the question/answer too much then I would usually not allow it.

Comment: @Chris — Sorry, I probably wasn't clear — I'm mostly concerned about the attempted insertion of links into the Edit Summary (see the line starting with "Comment:" in the screenshot).

Comment: The links may be unhelpful, but why do you think they are inappropriate?

Comment: Spam in edit summaries has been a thing before, and something that SE has filters to avoid. If the links aren't spam or self promotional and the edits themselves are legit it seems like a low priority concern to me. I agree it's weird and not particularly helpful, though.

Comment: @canadianer — They make it very difficult to understand the summary of changes, which seems counterproductive and makes comprehension by the OP (and reviewers) needlessly difficult. The spam-like appearance also could lead someone to reject these edits without really reading them (I came very close).

Comment: @BryanKrause — OK, thanks! I guess I'l just leave this person a comment if I see more of these and link to this meta question  ...

Comment: The Wikipedia link about the spelling of coronavirus might be ok (as in explanatory for the OP), while those (youtube) links for plain English language fixes seem a bit excessive to me. (Those might be appropriate on a site like ELL.SE)

Comment: It's amusing that the person is editing the boiler plate code that is never seen by users  "enter image description here" by capitalizing "enter". If he wants to improve the post, he should do like it says — enter an image description. (I'm surprised he didn't add the article). He would do well to restrict himself to important changes. I don't like ":-" either, but even I wouldn't impose my style on a poster to that extent. And if anyone did it to me...